# Make a Connection string for HANA JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

```
String databaseURL = "jdbc:sap://<HOST_NAME>:30015/<DATABASE_NAME>";
Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, <user><password>);
```

I am using ngdbc-2.3.48.jar.
Connection is being established using the UI in Eclipse.

But not from the above code. Giving Below Exception:

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecExceptionSapDB: [10]: authentication failed
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:165)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:42)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.HReplyPacket._buildExceptionChain(HReplyPacket.java:977)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.HReplyPacket.getSQLExceptionChain(HReplyPacket.java:158)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.HPartInfo.getSQLExceptionChain(HPartInfo.java:40)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB._receive(ConnectionSapDB.java:3115)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.exchange(ConnectionSapDB.java:1518)
    at com.sap.db.util.security.AbstractAuthenticationManager.connect(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:41)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB._getNewSession(ConnectionSapDB.java:3496)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB._getNewConnection(ConnectionSapDB.java:2813)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.<init>(ConnectionSapDB.java:198)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.HanaConnection.<init>(HanaConnection.java:39)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.HanaConnectionFinalize.<init>(HanaConnectionFinalize.java:36)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.HanaConnectionFinalize.newInstance(HanaConnectionFinalize.java:23)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB._createConnection(DriverSapDB.java:1445)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.Topology.getConnection(Topology.java:200)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB._connect(DriverSapDB.java:1400)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB.connect(DriverSapDB.java:1102)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.test(HANATest.java:429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Kindly please help me with the connection string.

Comment: "*authentication failed*" seems to indicate you are providing the wrong username or password

Comment: Your code won't even compile.  You should refer to the [HANA documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/ff15928cf5594d78b841fbbe649f04b4.html) covering JDBC connection strings.